# Different scalebars in 2 maps showing the same areas

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis

I am producing maps using ggplot2 and adding a scalebar using ggsn.

When I produce the same map using the 3857 CRS and the 4326 CRS, the scalebars are different when I would have expected them to be the same.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(geojsonio)
 library(ggsn)
 #load the boundary file
 map<-geojsonio::geojson_read("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/f03c3abfc3554841b83a43921bbd1817_0.geojson", what = "sp") %>%
 sf::st_as_sf()

#tranform to CRS 4326
 map4326<-sf::st_transform(map,crs=4326)

 #plot map in CRS 4326
 ggplot()+
 ggplot2::geom_sf(data=map4326)+
 ggsn::scalebar(map4326,dist=200, dist_unit="km", transform=TRUE,location="bottomleft", st.size=3,model = "WGS84")
```

[image: CRS 4326 Map]

```
 #transform to CRS 3857
 map3857<-sf::st_transform(map,crs=3857)
 #plot map in CRS 3857
 ggplot()+
 ggplot2::geom_sf(data=map3857)+
 #using transform=FALSE in the scalebar function because units for CRS 3857 are in meters
 ggsn::scalebar(map3857,dist=200, dist_unit="km", transform=FALSE, location="bottomleft", st.size=3)
```

[image: CRS 3857 Map]

The first map (CRS 4326) appears accurate whereas on the second map (CRS 3857) the scalebar seems to underestimate the distance. Can anyone suggest how the scalebar on the second map can be fixed to be more accurate?

Comment: the 2nd one is missing the model that the other one has

Comment: the model is only used by the function if transform=TRUE, because the units for CRS 3857 is in metres (2nd map) then the function required transform=FALSE. Therefore even if a model is entered for the 2nd map, it will be ignored by the function.

Comment: While 3857 is in "metres" they should not be used to measure anything as they expand as you go north (or south), so you probably want a transform of some type. If you are only interested in GB then use EPSG:27700 instead

Comment: The maps I create can also use tiles from web services such as Open Street Map as a background map which are in 3857 so for these types of map I need to use 3857.